# CompletableFuture - skip errors and take only validate data

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a specific code which is working fine if webclient response is OK. If any error, then the get() method throwing error and the thread blocked forever.

```
@SneakyThrows
public List<ResponseData> validateExpression(List<RequestData> RequestDataList, Data data) {
    System.out.println(Instant.now());
    final List<Mono<ResponseData>> monoList = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestDataList.parallelStream().forEach(requestData -> {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            log.info("Diversity API request data:");
            log.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(requestData));
            Mono<ResponseData> monoResponse = webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("http://...")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header(API_KEY_HEADER, config.getApiKey())
                    .body(Mono.just(requestData), RequestData.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(ResponseData.class);
            System.out.println("create mono response lazy initialization");
            monoList.add(monoResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Instant.now());
    CompletableFuture<List<ResponseData>> futureCount = new CompletableFuture<>();
    List<ResponseData> responseDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    Mono.zip(monoList, Arrays::asList)
            .flatMapIterable(objects -> objects)
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                futureCount.complete(responseDataList);
            }).subscribe(responseData -> {
                responseDataList.add((ResponseData) responseData);
    });
   return futureCount.get();
}
```

It is working fine with successful case. If there is any error from the webclient it is throwing error and thread blocked forever.
How to skip the errors and get only validate response data ?
How to avoid deadLock on this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `CompletableFuture::get` method's doc:
[image]

It throws three different checked exceptions. Lombok's `@SneakyThrows` annotation hides them so they aren't managed by your method. You should probably add a `try`/`catch` block to manage these exceptions and skip the errors if you want so.

Comment: I tried with try and catch block as well. However my concern is it return success response and skip any exception/ error response.